# VBA Array Type Mismatch

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Trying to set the split cell to an array, getting a type mismatch error.  I am trying to match the second element of the array with the value of Department, then put the value of sumpay into the 4th cell of that row.

```
Sub Pay_Period_Summarization()
'
' Pay_Period_Summarization Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'

Dim wb As Object
Dim ws As Object
Dim ws2 As Object
Dim rg As Object
Dim rg2 As Object
Dim row As Object
Dim row2 As Object
Dim Department As String
Dim sumpay As Currency
Dim count As Integer
Dim Dept() As Variant


count = 0
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("AD2").End(xlDown))

Department = ""
For Each row In rg.Rows

    If count = 0 Then
        sumpay = sumpay + row.Cells(1, 11).Value
        Department = row.Cells(1, 1).Value
        count = count + 1
    Else

        If Department <> row.Cells(1, 1).Value Then

            Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Journal Entry")
            Set rg2 = ws2.Range("B2", ws2.Range("P2").End(xlDown))

            For Each row2 In rg2.Rows
                Dept = Split(row.Cells(1, 2), "-")
                If Dept(2) = Department Then
                    row.Cells(1, 4).Value = sumpay
                Else

                End If
            Next row2
            sumpay = 0


        Else

            'MsgBox (row.Cells(1, 11).Value)
            sumpay = sumpay + row.Cells(1, 11).Value
        End If
    End If

    'MsgBox (sumpay)
Next row

End Sub
```

I am getting the error at the " If Dept(2) = Department Then".  Any help is appreciated as this is my first time writing a macro.  I am unfamiliar with how arrays work in VBA.

Comment: Note that `Split` returns a zero-based array so the 2nd element would be `1`, not `2`.

Comment: I prefer to add the index on the same line rather doing it later which requires you to find 2 lines to figure out what `Dept` is - or at least in this context. So, `Dept = Split(row.Cells(1, 2), "-")(1)`

Comment: Why use `Dim rg As Object` rather than `Dim rg As Range`? Using the latter allows the VBA editor to help you more with Intellisence. Using the generic `Object` for an Excel object just makes your code harder to write and harder to debug with no compensating advantage. While on the topic of variable types, using `Long` is almost always preferable to using `Integer` since the number of rows in a modern spreadsheet can overflow `Integer`.

Comment: Dim Dept() as variant declares an array of variants.  What Split returns is a variant containing an array.  The two are not the same even though the syntax for accessing individual members of the array is identical.  Therefore the () are not needed in the declaration.